# Why is R grouping my headers?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and when I am trying to upload data from a source, it relays my headers as a single header separated by full stops. How do I get it to recognise separate columns as separate headers?

So I used

```
data <- read.table(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
```

and the result was

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   113 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ id.weight0.weight8.IGG.died.litter.multiple: Factor w/ 113 levels "1,5.1,25.8,69.2,0,1,0",..: 1 26 37 48 59 70 81 92 103 2 ...
```

Comment: Is it a csv file?  You probably need to adjust the `sep` argument in `read.table`.  Its default is `""` If it's  csv, then `sep = ","` should work.  Or just use `read.csv`

Comment: do you also know how I can plot a histogram for an individual header do I need to get it to recognise this first?

Comment: Fix the data input problem. Learn to use `colClasses=` and `sep=`